# Displaying JSON Data Using Angular 7

Tags: json, angular

I am attempting to display this JSON data from the server:

```
{"buySell":
[
  {"date":"2015-03-02","close":120.351,"buySell":"Sell"},
  {"date":"2019-01-02","close":157.2455,"buySell":"Buy"}
],

"firstReturn":0.62987323647548421,
"sell":{"date":"2018-10-08","close":222.0396},
"buy":{"date":"2018-05-02","close":173.9216}
}
```

This is how I format it in HTML:

```
<mat-list *ngIf="buySellData$ | async as stock else noData">
   <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of stock ">
       {{item.listOfBuySell | json}} 
   </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

This is the stock format

```
stock: Cagr[];
```

and carg.ts is:

```
import { Istock } from './istock'
import { Dateclose } from './dateclose'

export class Cagr {
    listOfBuySell: Istock;
    close: number;
    sell: Dateclose;
    buy : Dateclose;
 }
```

istock.ts is:

```
 export class Istock {
    date: Date;
    close: number;
    buysell: string;
}
```

and finally dateclose.ts

```
export class Dateclose {
    date: Date;
    close: number;
}
```

This is the error I get in displaying:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type  'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Comment: Are you confusing classes and interfaces? Classes have constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over an **object** but not **array**. This causes such error.

You should check what exactly you have as a result in `buySellData$ | async`.